# How to replace text to nothing after some specific keyword?

Tags: notepad++

I've a list like this (over 1000):

```
Hello*123
Hi*259
King*555
```

I want to delete `*123`, `*259`, `*555` from each line and want to make it like

```
Hello
Hi
King
```

How to do so? I'm using Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

If you can rely on the pattern `Asterisk Digit Digit Digit` then you can do a Replace All using the regex `\*\d{3}`. Make sure you have the `Regular expression` option selected.

[image: Notepad++ Regular Expression]

Comment: The solution is right, but only works if the digits after the asterisk are exactly 3 (as the examples provided). It lenght can be variable, then you should use `\*\d+` instead.